# Show a gif as a select option

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with C#, Razor, .Net Framework 4.7 and jQuery 3.2.1

I'm trying to show a gif in a select, while I load its options with ajax.

This is the select:

```
@Html.DropDownList("productionOrderId",
        new SelectList(Model, "ProductionOrderId", "Name"),
        @Resources.IndexAggLevelProOrdCaption,
        new { id = "ProductionOrderSelect", @class = "productSelect" })
```

And this is the jQuery that loads the new options into the select:

```
function UpdateList(radioButton) {
    $('#productionOrderTable').empty()

    var URL = $(radioButton).data('checkaction');
    var phase = $(radioButton).val();

    var selectList = $("#ProductionOrderNameSelectId");
    var firstOption = selectList.find('option:first-child');

    selectList.find('option').remove();
    selectList.append('<option><img src="~/images/loadingDropDown.gif"/></option>');

    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { phase: phase },
        success: function (response) {
            var selectList  = $("#ProductionOrderNameSelectId");
            //selectList.find('option').not(':first').remove(); // remove all elements except for first one
            //selectList.add(firstOption);

            //for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            //  $(selectList).append(new Option(response[i].Item2, response[i].Item1))
            //}         
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

The content inside the `ajax` function is commented because I'm checking why I don't see the gif.

I have tried this:

```
selectList.append('<option><img src="~/images/loadingDropDown.gif"/></option>');
```

And, in firefox, I get an empty option: `<option></option>`.

I have also tried:

```
selectList.append('<option style="background-image:url(~loadingDropDown.gif);"></option>');
```

But here, it doesn't find the image.

The image is in the folder `~/image/`.

How can I show an icon as an option in a select?

Comment: Native HTML selects do not support images

Comment: You cannot add HTML elements within `option`, and you cannot reliably style them either. If you need the animated loading icon to be *inside* the `select`, then you will need to use a third-party library such as `Select2`. Otherwise, it's much, *much* easier to just put the icon *next* to the select.

Comment: Ok. I saw somewhere a select with an icon moving while its content is loading. Maybe, I can use a text like `<option>Loading...</option>` if I don't want to use third-party libraries. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: jQuery UI has a `select` style control that allows you to style your options as you like with images and what not: https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

Comment: As Rory says, you could just put your loading icon at the side of the select, right next to it. I've seen that in sites before, it works fine. Users will get the idea.